# I need a jquery menu bar implementation similar to MenuMatic

Tags: jquery, mootools

I need a jquery implementation of a horizontal menubar similar to [ManuMatic](http://greengeckodesign.com/projects/MenuMatic/examples/horizontal/index.htm).

I found [mb.menu](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb._menu/menu.html) but it seems to require `tables` instead of `ul`. I need this to work with `ul` because I'm not allowed to change the HTML producing code.

1. Is there any implementation of something like mb.menu but using only nested `ul`?
2. Can use MooTools along with jquery without trouble?

UPDATE: It that @bobince already answer the second question on [Can jQuery and Mootools work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352806/can-jquery-and-mootools-work-together)

Comment: Out of curiosity, and a strange desire to help, what **is** the produced html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a jQuery UI plugin as you wish.
Please try it if you like.:-)

https://github.com/madguy/jQuery.ui.smoothMenu

Comment: This seems to be what I need. However english comments would be appreciated ;). I'm forking it on github.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons.  Here are couple that's done by with jQuery that i used before.  This demo for the first attaches onClick event but i modified it to use for hover and etc:

[jQuery DropDown](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html)

[Superfish jQuery Dropdown](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#)

jQuery can be used in no-conflict mode:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

or could use jQuery instead of $.  this is definately a duplicate question on that.

Comment: Mootool 1.3 also won't use the $ function if its already being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flashheader/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //code you need to use
    });  
</script>
```

It helped me yith JQuery conflict. Hope it wil help you too.