# jquery.noconflict for mootools & jquery

Tags: html, mootools, compatibility, jquery

I've seen this question being asked 1000 times, but I'd tried almost all methods and I'm not sure why its not working for me -__-".  I have quite a few .js files.  Some pertaining to jquery, some for mootools.  I've tried moving jquery files to the top and adding a noconflict script.  When I do that, only the mootools work.  But the order of things doesn't resolve the issue.  If I don't do anything, both scripts won't work.

I've checked to make sure all jquery functions are using jquery(); instead of $();.  Mootools is still using $ functions though. Through testing, i found that jquery1.26min.js is the culprit.  But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any tips would help, thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far btw the  tags, the first two script lines shouldn't affect anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/minmax.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="includes/mootools.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="includes/mootoolt.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="includes/Fx.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="includes/BarackSl.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="includes/demo.js"></script>

<script src="includes/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script> 

<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery.noConflict(); </script>

<script src="includes/jquery-easing.1.2.js" type='text/javascript'></script> <script src="includes/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.js" type='text/javascript'></script> <script src="includes/coda-slider.1.1.1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {             
     $("#blogSlider2").codaSlider();        
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: you should put the `jQuery.noConflict();` in a script tag.  which version of mootools are you using? if you are using mootools 1.3 then the `$` will not conflict with jquery' and thus no need for `noConflict();`

Comment: It seems MooTools has found a nice solution for conflict management: http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this

```
$(function () {             
     $("#blogSlider2").codaSlider();        
});
```

should better be

```
jQuery(function () {             
         jQuery("#blogSlider2").codaSlider();        
    });
```

Comment: or even better, use `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` so you can use `$j()` instead of the ugly `jQuery()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i'll incorporate them in as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `noConflict()` looks out of script tag (It was intentional or typo).

Anyway You should look at these two answers on SO:

[Can jQuery and Mootools work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352806/can-jquery-and-mootools-work-together/3353309#3353309)

[Can jQuery and Mootools work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352806/can-jquery-and-mootools-work-together/3352820#3352820)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Yes there should be script tags, I'm not sure why that disappeared.  I've been to http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries and used the code there.  What am I supposed to change inside that code?  What does div and someid supposed to refer to?

Comment: which version of mootools are you using?

Comment: i have mootools.js (1.2.1) and mootoolt.js (1.2.2.2)

Comment: in light of that comment, i changed the mootools.js to mootools-core-1.3-full-compat.  The most updated version.  And updated the jquery to jquery-1.4.4.min.js.  Test both and they work individually.